# mimetype docx is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using MIME types to check the content of the file before uploading. I use byte array sequences to determine the correct MIME type of a given file.

```
public class MimeType
{
    private static readonly byte[] DOC = { 208, 207, 17, 224, 161, 177, 26, 225 };
    private static readonly byte[] GIF = { 71, 73, 70, 56 };
    private static readonly byte[] JPG = { 255, 216, 255 };
    private static readonly byte[] MP3 = { 255, 251, 48 };
    private static readonly byte[] PDF = { 37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46 };
    private static readonly byte[] PNG = { 137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82 };
    private static readonly byte[] RAR = { 82, 97, 114, 33, 26, 7, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] WAV_AVI = { 82, 73, 70, 70 };
    private static readonly byte[] DOCX = { 50, 75, 03, 04 };//MS Office Open XML Format Document
    // private static readonly byte[] DOCX = { 50, 75, 03, 04, 14, 00, 06, 00};MS Office 2007 documents
    // private static readonly byte[] ZIP_DOCX = { 80, 75, 3, 4 };

    public string GetMimeType(byte[] file, string fileName)
    {
        string mime = "application/octet-stream"; //DEFAULT UNKNOWN MIME TYPE
        //Ensure that the filename isn't empty or null
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
        {
            return mime;
        }

        //Get the file extension
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName) == null
                               ? string.Empty
                               : Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToUpper();
        //Get the MIME Type
        if (file.Take(8).SequenceEqual(DOC))
        {
            mime = "application/msword";
        }
        else if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(GIF))
        {
            mime = "image/gif";
        }
        else if (file.Take(3).SequenceEqual(JPG))
        {
            mime = "image/jpeg";
        }
        else if (file.Take(3).SequenceEqual(MP3))
        {
            mime = "audio/mpeg";
        }
        else if (file.Take(7).SequenceEqual(PDF))
        {
            mime = "application/pdf";
        }
        else if (file.Take(16).SequenceEqual(PNG))
        {
            mime = "image/png";
        }
        else if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(WAV_AVI))
        {
            mime = extension == ".AVI" ? "video/x-msvideo" : "audio/x-wav";
        }
        else if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(DOCX))
        {
            // mime = extension == ".docx" ? "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" : "application/vnd.ms-word";
            mime = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        }
        else
        {
            mime = "not valid file";
        }
        return mime;
    }
}
```

In the above code when I try to upload docx file I will get result as not valid file. Can anyone suggest me what is wrong in the above mentioned code byte array value of docx or contenttypeof the docx. I am using ASP.NET 4.5 framework.

Comment: Aaaaand what are the first 4 bytes of that document? I have a few docx files on my PC which don't seem to be real docx files.

Comment: And maybe you want to read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Comment: and in above code i have commented one more docx array byte sequence it contains 8 bytes am confused which one i have to use and why am not able to check the docx file and not able to upload file

Comment: Please, use a hex editor and tell us what you see at the beginning of the file that you're trying to upload.